# CHttpException exception in YII

Tags: php, linux, yii

I have developed a web application on Yii.

I have deployed it on 2 servers.
I can access a page called via statistics controller on the second server. It works all okay on my local host too but on the 1st server it gives me the exception

```
CHttpException You are not authorized to perform this action.
```

This exception takes places when the access is not defined in the access rules in yii. I have defined the permissions of this index as '@' that means all the logged in users can access it.

Any ideas behind this exception?

```
public function filters() {
    return array('accessControl'); // perform access control for CRUD operations
}

public function accessRules() {
    return array(
        array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform 'create' and 'update' actions
            'actions' => array( 'index'),
            'users' => array('@'),
        ),
        array('deny', // deny all users
            'users' => array('*'),
        ),
    );
}
```

//this is what that is being called

```
 public function actionIndex()
 {   ...
```

Comment: Can you post `accessRules()` and `filters()` methods in your controller?

Comment: @hamed modified the question, you can see them now

Comment: Are you sure that you are authenticated when you perform that action? Try to replace `'users' => array('@')` with `'users' => array('*')` and check is there any change in details of `CHttpException`.

Comment: yes, already tried that..it is not working.. the strange thing is the same code is working in another server... @hamed and yes rest of the pages with the same set of rules are working fine..

Comment: Are you sure you are not redirecting upon controller call?  Put an Yii::app()->end() on the first line of the index action to test this,

Answer (score 0):

That could be due to poor exception handling may be. The data in mysql somehow got corrupted on this server, I moved the data of working app server to this one and it started to work.

Even I tried die(); and printed the result set and it was working and shown on the UI but somehow Yii couldn't render that data on the view...Pretty strange but some how got it solved.

Thanks,
Danyal